# observer event after order invoice status paid executed in magento 2

Tags: event-observer, sales-order, invoice, magento-2.1.3

I am working on this Magento 2 extension and part of the features is need to entry in another table where order total will be inserted. so what I need is to find order invoice status paid event observer.How can I get order invoice status paid event in observer?

Comment: what do you mean by order paid?

Comment: Once full invoice is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of Magento 2 events.

https://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

In your case you can use `sales_order_invoice_pay` event which is calling from below location inside **pay() function**.

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Invoice.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch('sales_order_invoice_pay', [$this->_eventObject => $this]);
```